# Loading JavaScript Function when loading new php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a button that includes a `location.href = "home.php"` This redirects to the home page fine, however if this button is pressed i need a function to run from the JavaScript. I don't want to do a document load in JavaScript as this should only appear when a certain button takes you home. I need to POST value and say `if(isset($_POST['value']))` I just cant get this to work.

```
 $(function () {
                $('#receiptButton').click(function () {

                     location.href = "home.php";
                     show_receipts();
                });
            });
```

i need the `show_receipts();` to run once home.php is loaded. I believe using ajax is the correct way, but i cant redirect to the page and run the function.

Comment: You mean AJAX then ? EDIT: Correct, you have modified your question by adding more information.

Comment: what have you tried so far?Put it over here.Without code nothing can be said.

Comment: If you want your function to run _after_ `home.php` is loaded, then you need to call it from `home.php`, not the page before it.  Once you call change `location.href`, that's it, the user is gone from that page. And changing `location.href` invokes a `GET` request, not a `POST`.

Comment: @PatrickQ how can i implement a POST ?

Comment: Usually either with a form submit or an ajax request. But I'll ask _why_ you want to do a `POST`.

Comment: @PatrickQ i have always been made to believe that GET is easier to interfere with and not shown in the url header,